# Register Estimote Beacons (Eddystone) with Google's Proximity Beacon API

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

Registering beacons with the Proximity Beacon API seemed easy, but I can't receive any messages with the Nearby Messages API (registered beacon, added attachments, subscribed with the messages API).

I think my problem lies with registering the beacon. It says that you're supposed to use the namespaceID and the instanceID, but every app I use to retrieve the ids tell me I either have to put 0x in front of the namespaceID/instanceID, or put : in between them.

I've tried the following formats:

- namespaceIDinstanceID
- namespaceID:instanceID
- 0xnamespaceIDinstanceID

I'm using Estimote beacons at the moment. How would I have to register Estimote beacons with Eddystone to the Proximity Beacon API?

**I don't need the code, just the Eddystone UID format before it's converted to base64.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express the Eddystone UID as a byte array that includes both the namespace and instance, so a total of 16 bytes.  Like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

// For namespace 0x0102030405060708090a, instance 0x0b0c0d0e0f00
byte[] myEddystoneUid = new byte[] {
        (byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x04,
        (byte)0x05, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x07, (byte)0x08,
        (byte)0x09, (byte)0x0a, (byte)0x0b, (byte)0x0c,
        (byte)0x0d, (byte)0x0e, (byte)0x0f, (byte)0x00
};

JSONObject advertisedId = new JSONObject()
        .put("type", "EDDYSTONE")
        .put("id", Base64.encodeToString(myEddystoneUid, Base64.NO_WRAP));
json.put("advertisedId", advertisedId);
json.put("status", "ACTIVE");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it solved my problem!